# "Add Sticky" texture option missing in Blender 2.7

Tags: texturing, uv

In this [video](http://youtu.be/WbWUZkxi9vQ?t=5m20s), the person adds a "sticky" texture to an object.  The effect is that the object takes on the appearance of the background so that he can use it to "hide" an object behind it.  My issue is that Blender 2.7 has removed "Add Sticky", and Sticky mapping.

I find if I use the same image texture and "Window" mapping coordinates, this has a similar effect, but if the actual background is a composite (for example, I have an image that has a transform and some other nodes on it) it doesn't take those into account. Anyway to incorporate those? Or to use the actual background? –

Comment: I find if I use the same image texture and "Window" coordinates, this has a similar effect, but if the actual background is a composite (for example, I have an image that has a transform and some other nodes on it) it doesn't take those into account.  Anyway to incorporate those?  Or to use the actual background?

Comment: Hi, you can include the above information in the main post by editing your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sticky coordinates [have been removed](http://www.mail-archive.com/bf-committers@blender.org/msg12511.html), the main idea is that you should substitute the ‘sticky’ function with ‘UV project from view’ instead.

If you don't want use the uv project,  an alternative is the [BLAM addon](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam#what-is-this).

Comment: This works well, but it still doesn't incorporate other compositions I've done on my background (like a translation.)  Right now on my object I'm specifying an image, is there anyway to specify the world background?